# Parsing a decimal number in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse a decimal number in one of my methods, but it keeps giving me a runtime error and I don't understand why. I have to calculate the final velocity of an object, but every time I try to enter a decimal number as a value, it gives me a runtime error, focusing on where I parsed the decimal.

```
private static decimal GetVelocity()
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter the intial velocity of the object: ");
        decimal mVelocity = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return mVelocity;
    }
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What is the error and what is that number you are typing?

Comment: and what do you type in the console?

Comment: You should include the input and the exception in your question. One possibility is that you are not writing the number in the format the program expects (e.g. `,` or `.` as decimal separator)...

Comment: Most probably, you are using comma as decimal separator

Comment: Never trust user input. Use `decimal.TryParse` instead of `decimal.Parse`.

Comment: there cannot be a correct answer unless you tell us what you enter in the console and what are the culture settings on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

`decimal.Parse` needs a valid decimal, otherwise it will throw an error. `1.5`, `1`, and `100.252` are all valid decimals in most cases with the default culture. The culture you're using may be attempting to convert a decimal using an incorrect separator (Like `,`). See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to use the overloaded `decimal.TryParse` to provide culture specific information.

Ideally, you should use `decimal.TryParse` to attempt to convert it, and display an error otherwise:

```
private static decimal GetVelocity()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the intial velocity of the object: ");
    decimal mVelocity;
    while ( !decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out mVelocity) )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid velocity. Please try again: ");
    }
    return mVelocity;
}
```

Comment: actually your answer is not entirely correct, it depends on the regional settings, coma or full stop

Comment: @ВиталийТерзиев Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If the input is in an invalid format `Parse` will throw an exception. You 2 options.

Wrap the call to parse in a try/catch block

```
decimal mVelocity;

try {
    mVelocity = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Or use `TryParse` instead.

```
decimal mVelocity;
bool success = Decimal.TryParse(value, out mVelocity)
```

You're code is throwing an exception because the input cannot be parsed to a decimal. [See msdn for examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Hi You can use regex instead.

```
    private static decimal GetVelocity()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]([.,][0-9]{1,3})?$");
        Console.Write("Please enter the intial velocity of the object: ");
        string decimalInput = Console.ReadLine();

        while (!regex.IsMatch(decimalInput))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong input");
            decimalInput = Console.ReadLine();
        } 

        decimal mVelocity = decimal.Parse(decimalInput);
        return mVelocity;
    }
```